# From where is the MSCRM_CONFIG database called?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

The database for our Dynamics CRM installation is clustered and located on two servers. Somewhere, the MSCRM_CONFIG database is called on one of the SQL instances instead of the cluster, leading to access problems.

I need to correct this and make sure the database is called on the cluster instead. Where can I look for places where MSCRM_CONFIG is called from (config files, services etc)?

**What I have tried without success**

- Looked in the config files for our custom-built CRM-related services
- Searched config files in the Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM folder for the name of the instance
- Looked at the Deployment Manager for the SQL Server for our CRM Organization

Answer (score 1):

Every Dynamics CRM Server (front-end and back-end as well as servers with the discovery or deployment role) can be expected to open connections to the MSCRM_CONFIG database. This database is needed to get e.g. the organization settings.

The connection string for the MSCRM_CONFIG database can be found on these servers in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM\configdb`.

Comment: Unfortunately the configdb value is set to the cluster on both our Dynamics CRM servers. I will have to continue looking.

Comment: You could also check the E-mail Router for CRM. Not sure if this component accesses CRM databases though.